# How do I increment the day of the week in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm attempting to do something like this but I feel like I'm way off. My foreach loop will return 6 results. I want them to show incrementing days of the week starting with tomorrow. So if today is Friday, the result would be Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $today = date("l");
?>

<?php 
foreach() {
  echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($today++)) . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although [John Conde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204204) is a nice demonstration of PHP's datetime and date interval and period capabilities, this simple task can be done much more concise with something like:

```
$date = new DateTime();
for( $days = 6; $days--; ) {
  echo $date->modify( '+1 days' )->format( 'l' ) . '<br>';
}
```

<sup>[View online demo](https://eval.in/834843)</sup>

I've used `l` (lowercase L) for the format here, as that prints the full weekday name like it was requested in the question, but `DateTime::format()` recognizes [any format supported by `date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters).

---

The reason your own example didn't work is because you can't increment the result returned by `date()` the way you intended; `date()` returns a `string`, not some object that magically understands that the increment operator (`++`) means: add one day. PHP doesn't support that kind of [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) to begin with.

And if you thought `date()` returned an `integer` (like `time()` does) that you could increment, it would still not increment it with one day but with one second.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$today = date("Y-m-d");

for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
  echo date('l', strtotime('+'.$i.' days', strtotime($today))) . "<br>";
}

?>
```